# Resource management plugin in django?

Tags: python, django, caching, file-upload

I need a file resource manager (that I would use for resource caching) that has the following capability:

- saves file to a selected directory with a non-conflicting name
- does not save a file twice if the content or the "original source" matches.

Does django have such plugin?

Comment: I cant follow exactly, but maybe it would be an option for you to write custom storage backends for your file/image fields...

Comment: I do so now, but if there was a plugin already, I'd just use that.

Comment: Please use this site for software recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (BTW, I think it would be better if software recommendations are allowed here, but that's the current state of the art).